# Help needed with PyWallet and wallet dump using MacOS

Tags: wallet, python

Could anyone please give me some guidance on how to perform a wallet dump using PyWallet on a MacBook (macOS 10.12 Sierra)? I’m not very savvy with this stuff at all. Have an old wallet.dat file from 2011 that I want to check all the keys from and was reading that doing a wallet dump would be an efficient way to do it without having to wait for the entire blockchain to sync on Bitcoin Core. Having a really hard time trying to figure out how to do it with almost no computer programming knowledge. So far I have Python 2.7 downloaded but am pretty stuck after that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Install Xcode
- Install MacPorts from https://www.macports.org/

Run these commands:

```
sudo port install python27 py27-twisted py27-pip py-bsddb python_select
sudo port select --set python python27
sudo easy_install ecdsa
```